# Magento 2 Particular order assign to sub-admin

Tags: magento2, sales-order, user-roles, role

Right now I am working with `Magento 2` package, there has one out-of-scope Magento task.

**=> Requirement:**

- Customer Place order
- Admin create sub-admins
- The super-admin assign the order to sub-admin( Either from order
  detailed page or order list page)
- After the sub-admin login, in order page, they can do the all
  necessary action (invoice, comments etc...)that particular order
  which was assigned by super-admin
- Super-admin can able do all the action for all the orders

I hope this scope is not covert in Magento2 default, is there have any third-party module or else anyone has some nearest scope of the above means

Kindly share the details, it will help us to accomplish the task

Thanks in advance for your help.